# How to differentiate between a credit card and debit card BIN

Tags: javascript

I understand the first 6 digits of a card whether a Debit,Credit else Prepaid card holds the key to the nomenclature of the card. What I would request is can we interpret by any simple mechanism by getting the first 6 digits of the card BIN whether it is a credit card,debit card else a prepaid card BIN.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with computer programming, much less javascript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with computer programming.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this information is not stored in card numbers since debit cards can be converted into credit cards without number change.

Answer (score -1):

Each issuer controls their own unique use of their assigned number range for credit or debit, etc. 
For this reason, the BIN lists constantly change.

BIN lists are availabe at: https://www.bindb.com/.
They update daily, and offer an API for retrieving current BIN codes.

Answer (score -1):

Let me tell you dome little more about BIN. BIN (bank identification number) the initial six numbers that appear on a credit/debit card. The BIN uniquely identifies the institution issuing the card, the type and category of the card.

If you have BIN, you can know: Payment system, issuing financial institution, type of the card (credit or debit), type of the card (Electron, Classic, Gold, Maestro, Standard,, Platinum, etc), and issuing country. But banks does not provide the direct details of the cards these days.

You can get the details of the card whether it is credit or debit using some online tools where they store and collect this data on daily basis. You can use https://www.vccgenerator.com/bin-checker.php this tool to identify the data of the BIN deatails.

Hope this helps.